# Flutter: Image instance from CameraImage with format ImageFormatGroup.jpeg

Tags: flutter, camera, jpeg

I'm using flutter camera library and
want to create Image instance from CameraImage which format is ImageFormatGroup.jpeg.

Comment: can you please elaborate  you question?

Comment: I merely want to get image instance from Camera Image which has ImageFormatGroup.jpeg